# How to change L and R bearings of a referenced glyph?

Tags: glyphs, font-forge

I created some glyphs with *element → build → build composite glyph.*

Now, Lbearing and Rbearing are locked.

How can I change the glyph’s bearings without using *Unlink References?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the glyph view, find the component that dictates the locked metrics (bearings). For example, if your composite glyph is *Ẋ*, this will be the *X.*
2. Select this component; right-click.
3. Choose *Get Info* from the menu that should appear.
4. Uncheck *Use my Metrics.*

You should now be able to adjust the bearings while still using the shapes and relative positions of the linked glyphs as created by *build composite glyph* or *build accented glyph.*